# validate drop down list echoed from php to html with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, forms

ok so, the title of this question might be a little confusing, and i will try to explain it to you:
i have a php file with an array containing multiple form fields like this:

```
$var = array(0 => '<input type=....>', 1=> '<input type=....>');
```

and i created a while loop to loop through the array to show them in a table, something like this:

```
echo '<table>';
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $num = $row['fieldId'];
    $field = $num.' '.$row['field'];
    echo '<tr><td>'.$field.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$var[$q].'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
    $q++;
  }; echo '</table>';
```

i included this php file in a html file so i can get a table with two columns, the first one with $field from the database and the second with $var[$q] which is some input field taken from the $var array. 
Believe it or not that actually works, now the problem is that inside that $var array i have a `<select>` field with multiple options, i want to validate that field with some javascript, but for some reason i can't get the values assigned in `<option value="SOMEVALUE">` . i don't know why but i can't, one thing i found weird is that in that $var array i have some radio buttons which i **CAN** validate with javascript.

**more info:**
the html file that includes the php file has this:

```
<html>....
<form name="mainForm">
  <?php
    include 'myPhpFile.php';
  ?>
  <input type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="functionToValidate();">
</form>
...</html>
```

so basically when i include my php file it creates a table and adds fields to it filling them with data from a mysql database and some input fields using the $var array shown above
all that works, but the problem is when i click the next button it calls a javascript function to validate the fields, everything works until it gets to the `<select>` input,
i can validate radio buttons, text fields and textareas but i can't validate those `<select>`

this is the javascript function i am using:

```
function myFunctionNameHere(){
if(!document.mainForm.p1_1[0].checked && !document.mainForm.p1_1[1].checked)
      alert("1 - some warning here");
    else if(!document.mainForm.p1_2[0].checked && !document.mainForm.p1_2[1].checked)
      alert("2 - some warning here");
    else if(!document.mainForm.p1_3[0].checked && !document.mainForm.p1_3[1].checked)
      alert("3 - some warning here");
    else if(!document.mainForm.p1_4[0].checked && !document.mainForm.p1_4[1].checked)
      alert("4 - some warning here");
    else if(!document.mainForm.p1_5[0].checked && !document.mainForm.p1_5[1].checked)
      alert("5 - some warning here");
    else if(!document.mainForm.p1_6[0].checked && !document.mainForm.p1_6[1].checked)
      alert("6 - some warning here");
    else if(document.mainForm.p1_7.value == "")
      alert("7 - some warning here");
    // this condition does not work:
    else if(document.mainForm.p1_8.selectedIndex == 0)
      alert("8 - some warning here);
   // can't get the selectd field from the html select field
    else
      window.location = "OTHERPAGE.html";
}
```

that's pretty much what the function does, all conditions work except for that one i put the comments on. (i'm still learning so don't laugh at my code... please.)

**Sorry i actually got this solved, there were some errors in the html code from my php array. Now it actually works.
Thanks.**

Comment: Could you post the parsed code of the problematic select element?

Comment: You are getting select tag by id or using some jquery magic ? (if you post some code, would be helpful)

Comment: If the javascript validation is the problem, you might want to post the code of that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.  Post the full page somewhere and let us look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how you access select values in javascript:

```
<form name="mainform">
    <select name="dropbox_select">
        <option value="value0">option0</option>
        <option value="value1">option1</option>
        <option value="value2">option2</option>
    </select>
</form>

document.forms.mainform.dropbox_select.options[0].value
document.forms.mainform.dropbox_select.options[1].value
document.forms.mainform.dropbox_select.options[2].value
```